# discord.js Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm writing a discord bot that temporarily assigns a role when anybody says a specific word. My code has been returning the following error, even though I don't think I have any errors in my code.

```
message.member.roles.add(role555.id);
                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`
```

Here is my code:

```js
async function bannedword(message) {
    let role555 = message.guild.roles.cache.get((r) => r.name === "Quarantined");

    setTimeout(() => {
        message.member.roles.add(role555.id);
    }, ms("1s"));
    setTimeout(() => {
        message.member.roles.remove(role555.id);
    }, ms("30m"));
}

client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content.includes("fart") && message.author.bot == false && isolations == true) {
        bannedword(message);
        message.channel.send(publicquarantined);
        message.author.send(dmquarantined);
    }
});
```

The message and dm are sent and work fine but for some reason, the role is not assigned and it spits out this error.

Comment: Are you sure your role555 variable contains the role you are trying to get ? In this case, the "Quarantined" role. Since the error message clearly stated that "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined" so the role555 is indeed _undefined_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not how `get()` works. get() requires a [Snowflake](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/Snowflake). I suppose what you are looking for, is `find()`. And in your case, the [find()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) method would work and would return, if the condition exists.

Comment: Glad to help you!!